# MVC Request.IsAuthenticated not correct in standard layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a MVC razor webpage, after login i show additional menu-options in my navbar with this code:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-inverse-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li id="menuOptionDevices">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Översikt", "Devices", "Home")
                            </li>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                            <li>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Logga ut", "Logout", "Home")
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                }
```

When i go back to the login-page i don't want to show these options, i do a auth logout in the controller:

```
public ActionResult BetaLogin()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return View();
}
```

But the menu-options are still shown, if i F5 they dissapear. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It must be loading the page from cache, you may try using 'must-revalidate' header

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932890/http-cache-control-max-age-must-revalidate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148884/difference-between-no-cache-and-must-revalidate