# Using must-revalidate with NSURLSession through React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, nsurlsession, cache-control

Within a sample demo app I'm using React Native in order to make network calls. Under the hood React Native uses `NSURLSession` with `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` as the default cache policy. When a network call is made, the response returned by the service contains these cache controls headers:

```
public, max-age=10, must-revalidate
```

What I'm able to notice is that `NSURLSession` does not honour the `10` seconds if `max-revalidate` is present. On the contrary if the latter is not present whenever a new network call is made within the `10` seconds, the cache response is returned, otherwise a new call is made.

Based on the [14.9.4 Cache Revalidation and Reload Controls](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.4) section this should not be the expected behaviour but maybe I'm wrong.

> Because a cache MAY be configured to ignore a server's specified
>   expiration time, and because a client request MAY include a max- stale
>   directive (which has a similar effect), the protocol also includes a
>   mechanism for the origin server to require revalidation of a cache
>   entry on any subsequent use. When the must-revalidate directive is
>   present in a response received by a cache, that cache MUST NOT use the
>   entry after it becomes stale to respond to a subsequent request
>   without first revalidating it with the origin server. (I.e., the cache
>   MUST do an end-to-end revalidation every time, if, based solely on the
>   origin server's Expires or max-age value, the cached response is
>   stale.)

I found a useful discussion on this subject:  [HTTP Cache Control max-age, must-revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932890/http-cache-control-max-age-must-revalidate). Based on the discussion, it seems that the protocol is a bit

> ambiguous here, but in practice I have found that must-revalidate
>   means it must revalidate regardless of max-age.

A very strange thing is that if I do the same with Android, using both `max-age` and `must-revalidate` the behaviour is correct. After `10` seconds a new request will be made. Within the `10` seconds no request is made.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and it seems that in iOS (using NSURLSession) whenever `must-revalidate` is set, the `max-age` is not taken into consideration. It's a different story for Android where these two values can be used together.

P.S. if someone expert in HTTP protocol has a clue on this subject, please let me know.