# Does the must-revalidate cache-control header tell the browser to only download a cached file if it has changed?

Tags: apache, http, caching, http-headers, cache-control

If I want browsers to load PDF files from cache until they changed on the server, do I have to use `max-age=0` and `must-revalidate` as cache-control headers?

If I would use another value (larger than 0) for `max-age` would that mean the revalidation would only happen once the max-age value was exceeded?

What would happen if I would only set the `must-revalidate` header without max-age?

I was reading through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932890/http-cache-control-max-age-must-revalidate) and I am not 100% sure.

Also, what exactly does revalidate mean? Does it mean the client asks the server if the file has changed?

On the contrary, I've read that cache-control no-cache pretty much does what I want to achieve. Cache and check with the server if there is a new version... so whats the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking about which headers should you configure to be sent from your server, and by "client" you mean "modern web browser"? Then the quoted question/answer is correct, so:

1. Yes, you should set both, but `max-age=0` is enough, (`must-revalidate` is the default behavior)
2. Yes, correct, the response would be served from local cache until max-age expires, after that it would be revalidated (once), then again served from local cache and so on
3. It is kind of undefined, and differs between browsers and the way you send request (clicking link from html, hitting reload button, typing directly in address bar and hitting enter). Generally, response should not be served directly from cache but it could either just be revalidated or full response can be requested from server.
4. Revalidate means that client asks server to send the content only if it has been changed since it was last retrieved. In order for this to work, in response to initial request server will send either one or both of:

   - `Etag` header (which contains hashed value of the content), which client will cache and send back in revalidation request as `If-None-Match` header, so server can compare clients cached Etag value with the current Etag on server side. If the value did not change, server will respond with `304 Not Modified` (and empty body), and if the value changed, server will respond with `200` and full (new) content
   - `Last-Modified` (which contains timestamp of the last content modification), and client will send that in revalidation request in `If-Modified-Since` header, which will be used on server side to detirmine the response (`304` or `200`)

`Cache-control: no-cache` might achieve the same effect in most of the (simple) cases. The situation where things get complicated is when there are [intermediate caches](https://www.fastly.com/blog/stale-while-revalidate-stale-if-error-available-today) between client and the server, or when you want to [tweak client](https://web.dev/stale-while-revalidate) behavior (for example when sending AJAX requests) and that is when most of the [caching directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) come into use